# Can't boot existing win10 install due to missing IRST driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I had windows 10 installed on an ssd for a first gen i5 laptop, now I put that drive in my new laptop with 11th gen i5 and can't boot into that Windows because 11th gen requires an 'Intel Rapid Storage Technology' driver which was, ofcourse, not installed for the previous laptop. It throws a BSOD saying 'missing_boot_drive'
How do I 'inject' the required driver into the existing windows installation? I have the inf files.

Comment: Changing the drive setting to AHCI should be enough.

Comment: @ChanganAuto No setting for that in new laptop's BIOS, and previous laptop was set on AHCI already.

Comment: Exactly because it was installed with AHCI it now requires AHCI to boot. Now, disabling Intel RST, if an option, should automatically enable AHCI. If that's not possible then you must reinstall Windows, something you should always do anyway. The installer should detect the previous installation and offer to keep your personal files (but you should have backups anyway and never rely on the lazy possibility of simply transplanting drives between systems). That's all.

Comment: Its just the browser logins I need from that windows. I could have used 'upgrade' option in installer but that wouldn't be fun would it? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Firefox and Google Chrome have sync features so unless you actively avoided using a Google account credentials in the latter or never used Firefox sync in the former that's a completely moot point.

Comment: Besides for the obvious licensing issues, it seems the simplest solution, is to put the drive back in the original equipment and prepare Windows for the move to the new hardware or simply disable Intel RST and put it in AHCI mode which has to be supported by the new hardware.